# Select the column data only the active page on Datatable.js

Tags: jquery, datatables, pagination, datatables-1.10

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

var plainArray = table
    .column( 0 )
    .data()
    .toArray();
console.log('plainArray='+plainarray);
```

The above can get all the page data column(0) to array.

```
plainArray=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
```

How can I just get one page (the active page or any choose page ) column(0) data

page one

```
plainArray=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

page two

```
plainArray=11,12,13,14,15,16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the order of the data using [selector-modifier](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) option of the [column()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column()) selector.

You can use the [page](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier#page) modifier that allows you to control if the selector should consider all data in the table, regardless of paging, or if only the rows in the currently displayed page should be used. You may give the following values to `page` modifier, or any page number.

- `all` (default) - Use the rows from all pages
- `current` - Use the rows from only the currently displayed page.

To get the data for the rows on the current page only:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
table.column(0, { page:'current' }).data();
```

Comment: It's great! Thank for your help!